# Pass a value from one page to another and select values from database where a column is the first page value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two pages, first is a page with table and the second page shows details from the table, for ex. Table shows No, Subject, Location, Date, And Piority but when i click one each row it pass the value from No Column to the second page and write it in No place. what i want in second page is to get details from database where No Column is the value i pass it from first page.

Here is my first page how i get the value to GET:

```
<?php
     if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="file.php?No=<?= $row['No'] ?>"><?= $row['No'] ?></a></td>
        <td><?= $row['subject'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['location'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['geo'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['date'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['piority'] ?></td>
        </tr>

<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

here is my second page that i want to get data from database with No variable from first page:

```
<?php
     $varPage = $_GET['No'];
     $servername = "localhost";
     $username = "bayansh_r";
     $password = "u)nHf,Amo)";
     $dbname = "bayansh_c";
     $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
     // Check connection
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     } 
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT `news` FROM `editor3` WHERE No = '".$varPage."'");

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
?>
```

and now i want to write the News here is my code:

```
<p style="font-family:B Zar; direction:rtl; font-size:165%;"> <?= $row['news'] ?> </p>
```

but i get NULL result in Paragraph. is there any thing wrong with my code????

Comment: At first execute `SELECT news FROM editor3 WHERE No = '".$varPage."'` this query into `phpmyadmin`. If Ok, Then adjust your Output code into `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ /*Here*/}`

Comment: @sumonSarker You mean the i should enter <p style="font-family:B Zar; direction:rtl; font-size:165%;"> <?= $row['news'] ?> </p> code to /*Here*/ ???/

Comment: Yes! @Farhad paikan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried. I'ts working...

```
<?php 
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 ?>
<p style="font-family:B Zar; direction:rtl; font-size:165%;"><?php echo   $row['news'];?></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is yourfirst page how i get the value to GET:

```
<?php
            if($result->num_rows > 0) {
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
                 <tr>
                 <td><a href="file.php?No=<?echo $row['No']; ?>"><? echo $row['No']; ?></a></td>
                    <td><? echo $row['subject']; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $row['location']; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $row['geo']; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $row['date']; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $row['piority']; ?></td>
                 </tr>
        <?php
               }
            }
        ?>
```

here is your second page that you want to get data from database with No variable from first page:

```
 <?php
    $varPage = $_GET['No'];
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "bayansh_r";
                    $password = "u)nHf,Amo)";
                    $dbname = "bayansh_c";
                    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    // Check connection
                    if (mysqli_connect_error) {
                         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                    } 
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT news FROM editor3 WHERE No = '".$varPage."'");

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){?>

     <p style="font-family:B Zar; direction:rtl; font-size:165%;"><?php echo    $row['news'];?></p> 

      <?php } ?>
```

Hope it will works if any problem please comment.

Comment: Yes.. you select news from database.At this section do simply as `<p><?php echo $row['news'];?></p>`.

Comment: you can also format the paragraph section according to your needs using css.

Comment: should i enter like = while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        <p style="font-family:B Zar; direction:rtl; font-size:165%;"> <p><?php echo $row['news'];?></p>
    }

Comment: ` while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){?>
        <p style="font-family:B Zar; direction:rtl; font-size:165%;"><?php    echo $row['news'];?></p> 
<?php    } ?>` try it...

Comment: @HikmatSijapti it says Connection failed:

Comment: no it is online on Hostgattor , Any ways thanks for the reply : )

Comment: you are welcome....Code is correct just make the right database connection and try it will works. And vote up thanks..

Comment: Sir now the connection works but again i get null result, i mean it write nothing but the code works

Comment: Did u make connection on first page?

Comment: yes i did is there any way that i can share my both page to you and you can see the error sir, Thanks : )

Comment: it is been 20days i am googling and working on it I tried every way but i get the NULL result every time.

Comment: ya you can share your all code...then it will be easy to solve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130324/discussion-between-farhad-paikan-and-hikmat-sijapati).